# cannot ls( myVector )

Tags: r, dataframe

I read a data.frame from an sqlite table:

```
sql <- paste( "SELECT co_id, co_name, mkt_id FROM co" )
co <- dbGetQuery( db, sql )
```

and get a valid result (it seems):

```
ls( co )
[1] "co_id"   "co_name" "mkt_id"
```

I then subset some data:

```
x <- co[ co$mkt_id == 5, 2 ]
x
[1] "Dongbu"   "Green"    "Hanwha"   "Heungkuk" "Hyundai"  "LIG"     
[7] "Lotte"    "Meritz"   "Samsung"  "KFCC"     "NCUF"     "NACF"
```

Having difficulties assigning this variable `x` to a `gcombobox`, I was trying to find the reason and (this being the reason or not) found:

```
ls( x )
Error in as.environment(pos) : no item called "Dongbu" on the search list
```

Can somebody explain what this means? Shouldn't `x` be an ordinary vector, and "Dongbu" just be the first element?

```
sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[8] base     

other attached packages:
[1] gWidgetsRGtk2_0.0-81 RSQLite_0.11.2       DBI_0.2-5           
[4] stringr_0.6.1        gWidgets_0.0-52      xtable_1.7-0        
[7] gridExtra_0.9.1      ggplot2_0.9.2.1     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_1.1-1   dichromat_1.2-4    digest_0.5.2       gtable_0.1.1      
 [5] labeling_0.1       MASS_7.3-22        memoise_0.1        munsell_0.4       
 [9] plyr_1.7.1         proto_0.3-9.2      RColorBrewer_1.0-5 reshape2_1.2.1    
[13] RGtk2_2.20.25      scales_0.2.2       tools_2.15.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument of the `ls` function, `name`, specifies the name of the environment. In General, this function is used to list the object in the specified environment.

If you run this function with `x` as first argument, the function looks for the environment `"Dongbu"`, which is the first string in `x`, but fails to find the environment.

If you want to have a look of the structure of an object, you should use the `str` function. Try `str(x)`.